# Problem converting stramreader text containing XML data when there is line break

Tags: c#, regex, xml, linq, streamreader

1. I have a log file that contains mix strings like XML and Jason.
2. I must extract each of them to get a desired output.
3. The xml_string contains  element which can have line break.
4. I first read the all lines and then break them using Environment.NewLine to get log_file_lines  and then get lines in IEnumerable for xml_lines and jason_lines.
5. However, the problem occurs when there is a new line within the xml_lines. Meaning I get half or unformatted xml_ lines in  field.
6. Is there any way in regex or remove these lines from the log_file_string  text itself and then pass t to log_file_lines ?
7. **The other option can be getting data between just to nodes  and  in xml_lines from the log_file_string using regex without looping as data is of 3 MB file :(**

here is how log_file_string appears:

```
2020-06-10T10:58:07.0792762Z [data_type_jason] {"person_id":"101", "order_id":"123"}
2020-06-12T10:58:07.0792762Z [data_type_xml] <?xml version="1.0"?><persons><person id = "101"><name>"Thomas Edison"</name><age>"35"</age><phone>"7777777777"</phone><address>"62  Ross Road, 
    MARSHAM, NR10 6EA"</address><country>"England"</country></person></persons>
2020-06-13T10:58:07.0792762Z [data_type_jason]  {"person_id":"102", "order_id":"140"}
2020-06-14T10:58:07.0792762Z [data_type_xml]<?xml version="1.0"?><persons><person id = "102"><name>"Louis Pasture"</name><age>"40"</age><phone>"99999999"</phone><address>"145  Thames Street, BOOSBECK, TS12 1AN"</address><country>"England"</country></person></persons>
```

Here is the full prototype baby:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml.Linq;
namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }//Form1

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String file_folder = @"X:\VS 2019\C Sharp\Test";
            String file_path = Path.Combine(file_folder, "log_file.txt");
            process_log_file_data(file_folder, file_path);
        }//Form1_Load

        private void process_log_file_data(String file_folder, String file_path)
        {
            String log_file_string = read_all_lines_from_file(file_folder, file_path);
            String[] log_file_lines = log_file_string.Split(new String[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

            //The other option can be getting data between just to nodes <persons> and </persons> in xml_lines from the log_file_string using regex but am not regex savvy :(
            IEnumerable<String> xml_lines = from line in log_file_lines
                                            where line.Contains("data_type_xml")
                                            select line;

            IEnumerable<String> jason_lines = from line in log_file_lines
                                              where line.Contains("data_type_jason")
                                              select line;

            XDocument xml_document = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"), new XElement("xml_data"));

            foreach (var xml_line in xml_lines)
            {
                String line = xml_line.Split(new String[] { "[data_type_xml]" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[xml_line.Split(new String[] { "[data_type_xml]" }, StringSplitOptions.None).GetUpperBound(0)].Trim();

            //here is the issue < persond id = "101" >< address > as the  there is a line break in log_file_lines  the xml_line = 2020-06-12T10:58:07.0792762Z [data_type_xml] <?xml version="1.0"?><person><person id = "101"><name>"Thomas Edison"<name><age>"35"</age><phone>"7777777777"</phone><address>"62  Ross Road
            XDocument temp_xml_document = XDocument.Parse(line); //Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: address, person, persons. Line 1, position 144.'
            }

            foreach (var jason_line in jason_lines)
            {
                //do something
            }
        }//process_log_file_data(String file_folder, String file_path)

        private String read_all_lines_from_file(String file_folder, String file_path)
        {
            FileInfo file_info = new FileInfo(file_path);
            if ((!file_info.Exists) || (file_info.Length == 0))
            {
                return String.Empty;
            }

            FileStream file_stream; StreamReader stream_reader; UTF8Encoding utf8_encoding; String file_text;
            file_stream = new FileStream(file_path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            utf8_encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);
            stream_reader = new StreamReader(file_stream, utf8_encoding);
            file_text = stream_reader.ReadToEnd();
            stream_reader.Close();
            file_stream.Close();
            return file_text;
        }//read_all_lines_from_file

    }//Form1 : Form

}//Test
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what the raw log file looks like?

Comment: Hi Magnus. Thank you for looking into this. I have updated the question and added the log file text at below. Thank you again for looking into this.

Comment: If there is a line break in the xml does the row still start with [data_type_xml]?

Comment: Yes. here is how it appears;

xml_line = 2020-06-12T10:58:07.0792762Z [data_type_xml] <?xml version="1.0"?><person><person id = "101"><name>"Thomas Edison"<name><age>"35"</age><phone>"7777777777"</phone><address>"62  Ross Road

Comment: I have updated the question and also quoted where the issue lies.

Comment: I personally would process each line in sequence.  If a line doesn't start with a datetime+type just append it to the last line processed.  Then do the actual interpretation in a 2nd pass.

Comment: Well Mark it is 3 MB text file :(

Comment: Well you don't NEED to read the whole file into memory anyway. You can perform your JSON and XML work while you're reading the text lines out of the file.

Comment: @captain-kenpachi how? :(

Answer (score 0):

### Parsing the log entries:

Try something like this:

```cs
public static IList<string> ParseLogs(string log_file_string)
{
    // The pattern of the beginning of each log entry
    var logprefixPattern = @"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d+Z \[data_type_(jason|xml)\] ";

    // Replace it with a symbol
    var splitPattern = "[log_entry]";
    var replaced = Regex.Replace(log_file_string, logprefixPattern, splitPattern);

    // Split the string with that symbol
    var splited = replaced.Split(splitPattern);

    // Now you get the list of logs.
    return splited;
}
```

My idea is given that you read all the content and stored into a variable `log_file_string`, you may look for the pattern of each log instead of read it line-by-line.

Looks like for each log entry it begins with the same pattern so you can split the log entry by that pattern.

If you want to separate the items into 2 groups: the xml logs and json logs, you can loop the splited results one by one and determine it by e.g. the beginning character (`{` is json and `<` is xml).

### Parsing the XML inside a log entry

Assuming that you want to parse the XML into a list of json strings and each string is a person, you can make use of `Newtonsoft.Json`:

```cs
public static IList<string> ParseXml(string xmlStr)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xmlStr);

    // assuming that each entry contains at least 1 person, and you want to extract those persons
    var ppl = doc.GetElementsByTagName("person");
    var results = new List<string>{};
    foreach(XmlNode p in ppl)
    {
        string jsonStr = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(p);
        results.Add(jsonStr);       
    }
    return results;
}
```

For simplicity I just return the json strings here. You can deserialize the `jsonStr` into some C# model you defined.

Comment: Hi Bemin. there are other garbage data too between these lines. i just put the data i need

Comment: What do you mean by _garbage data_? Any example for that?

Comment: @Benn, Your idea is great. sadly am not regex savvy. Is it possible to get data between 2 xml tags from the log without any loop using regex? I mean between the tags <persons> and </persons>

the garbage data is infect very confidential information. I can't share it here. but that is of no use for my project

Comment: @JD you can parse the XML string as a `XElement` and retrieve the content / attributes you want. See [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-parse-a-string#example) on how to parse a string into the `XElement`. Don't use regex to parse a XML string.

Comment: Thanks @Bemn. It was really usefull :) . I m going to implement this in my project for sure. However, the challenge still remains where in the line containing xml string breaks :(. That's why i wanted to get a regex which can give me the collections of string between   <persons> and </persons> that can break the log file string

Comment: @JD See the edited answer above. The example should gives you an idea on how to parse the persons in the XML content. If you found the above snippets are useful you can also mark that as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using recursion and streamreader this can be achieved as follows.
Idea is reading two readlines simultaneoulsy with few conditions as ...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("filename"))
        {
            while (!r.EndOfStream)
            {
                var fline = r.ReadLine();
                string sline = "";
                if (!r.EndOfStream)
                    sline = r.ReadLine();

                RecursivelyParse(r,ref fline, ref sline);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void RecursivelyParse(StreamReader r, ref string fline, ref string sline)
    {
        if (fline.Contains("data_type_xml"))
        {
            if (!(sline.Contains("data_type_xml") || sline.Contains("data_type_jason")) && sline != "")
            {
                fline += sline;
                sline = "";
                //Next line also a part of xml
                //parsing loggic of line containing  xml 
            }
            else
            {
                //parsing loggic of line containing  xml 
            }
        }
        else if (fline.Contains("data_type_jason"))
        {
            //parsing loggic of line containing  jason 
        }

        if (sline.Contains("data_type_xml"))
        {
            if (!r.EndOfStream)
                fline = r.ReadLine();
            else
                fline = "";

            if (!(fline.Contains("data_type_xml") || fline.Contains("data_type_jason")) && fline != "")
            {
                sline += fline;
                fline = "";
                //Next line also a part of xml
                //parsing loggic of line containing  xml 
            }
            else
            {
                //parsing loggic of line containing  xml 
            }
        }
        else if (sline.Contains("data_type_jason"))
        {
            //parsing loggic of line containing  jason 
        }

        while (!r.EndOfStream)
        {
            fline = r.ReadLine();

            if (!r.EndOfStream)
                sline = r.ReadLine();
            else 
                sline = "";

            RecursivelyParse(r, ref fline, ref sline);
        }
    }

}
```